# Get telegram user id without chat

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have user's id in telegram. Outside bot. Just ids. Can I somehow get rest information about these users without chat with them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where has your research led you? Can we see the code you have tried?

Comment: @JasonAllshorn, I tried only `getChat` from telegram bot open api. But this allow me get user only if he already started messaging with my bot. Also i tried to google it and learned mtproto. But have no any usefull results.

Comment: @Sean, to forward message i need users start messaging with my bot. But i not want  open chat with them. I need to do this without messaging with users

Comment: @veselisk You can forward any message in group

Comment: @Sean, i still need some action from users. This is unacceptable for me. If I misunderstood you, give me an example. On java, js or python

Comment: @veselisk What do you mean by User ID? The telegram User ID that is a long number or Telegram username?

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi, i mean exactly telegram User ID that a long number

Comment: As I know Telegram bot api don't have independent method that returns information about user.

Comment: @sKwa, yes, you are right. But my question not about api only. I hope it possible to do with mtproto